# Complex mathematical expression c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new to c# and I want to make a pretty simple (in my opinion) program for my end of semester course. 
The algorithm in C looks like this. It calculates debit of a fluid with Venturi effect:

```
delta_p= p2-p1;
sectiune_rel=s1/s2;

numarator = 0.5*densitate*(pow(sectiune_rel, 2)-1);
raport = delta_p/numarator;
viteza1 = sqrt(raport);

debit = s1*viteza1;
```

I want to make a simple windows form with c#:

```
private void Butonrezultat_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double p1, p2, densitate1, s1, s2, sectiune_rel, debit;

        double.TryParse(presiunemare.Text, out p1);
        double.TryParse(presiunemica.Text, out p2);
        double.TryParse(densitate.Text, out densitate1);
        double.TryParse(sectiunemare.Text, out s1);
        double.TryParse(sectiunemica.Text, out s2);


         sectiune_rel = s1 / s2;
         debit = s1 * Math.Sqrt((p2 - p1) / ((0.5 * densitate1 * Math.Pow(sectiune_rel, 2) - 1)));


            rezultat.Text = debit.ToString("c"). Remove(0 , 1);
    }
```

Every time I debug it doesn't show anything to rezultat textbox. Do I miss something? I spend like two days on tutorials and I really couldn't find anything similar.

Comment: use instead of TextBox NumericalUpDown controls, so you don't have to Parse to double.

Comment: go to first line of the function, Press F9 to set a breakpoint. Press F10 to execute till next line. Watch the values. Where exactly your code break?

Comment: Your use of `.ToString("c"). Remove(0 , 1)` seems bad. It formats the number as a currency amount, and then removes `1` char from the resulting string starting at index `0`. Are you in a culture where the currency symbol consists of one character which is prepended to the amount, like `"$17.85"`? There are other cultures. Consider `.ToString("N")` (rounds to "default" numbers of digits, and groups digits in large numbers in groups), or `.ToString("F")` (without grouping), or, if you want to override the number of decimals, e.g. `.ToString("N2")` or `.ToString("F2")`.

Comment: I saw in a tutorial that they used it to format with 2 decimals. Toke it like that :d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems your method `Butonrezultat_Click` is not attached with click event of your button. 
Do Following

1. Select your button `Butonrezultat` in Design Mode of your Form
2. Click on Events button on top of Properties Window.
3. Scroll the events of `Butonrezultat`Button and search for `Click`
4. Select `Butonrezultat_Click` method from the drop down for click event.
5. Run Your Code

[image]

Comment: How did you figured it out, tho?

Comment: I have not found anything incorrect in your code and this problem i have faced when i was a beginner..